# Getting response of a system to a signal when step response is given

Tags: signal-processing

I have response of a system to Unit step function , how do u find the response of the system to a given x(t). Like if we have unit impulse function's response we use convolution.

Any reading material will be appreciated

Thanx

Answer (score 4):

Differentiate the unit step response, and you get the impulse response.  As you already know, determining the system response from a arbitrary input can then be found by convolving that arbitrary input with the impulse response.